# can not compile java program getting this 2 erros

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

```
Note: Hifidse.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

when i comple my java program using linux terminal by typing this command:

```
javac -cp org.tartarus.snowball.jar filename.java
```

i am getting above error after that when run the program uaing the command:

```
java -cp org.tartarus.snowball.jar filename arg1 arg2
```

i am getting this message:

```
error could not find or locate main class file filename
```

can any one help me on this thankyou.

Comment: is `filename.java` in a package?

Comment: Looks like a [dup of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749786/uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations)? Please post your code.

Comment: it is in src folder